# How can i extract all links from html document using htmlagilitypack?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(s1);

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    count++;
                    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                    if (att.Value.StartsWith("http") && !listBox1.Items.Contains(att.Value))
                        listBox1.Items.Add(att.Value);
                }
```

I'm getting for example 151 results but in fact there are more then 300.
In many cases where it found links it contain more then one link inside for example:

```
href="http://www.test.com dfsdfgfg https://www.test1.com 656567 http://test2.com
```

In this cases i need to break it so it will show me and count as 3 links and not one.
I tried to change att.Value.StartsWith("http") to att.Value.Contains("http") but that's not the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
                {
                    count++;
                    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                    foreach (var link in att.Value.Split(' ')) {
                       if (link.StartsWith("http") && !listBox1.Items.Contains(link))
                           listBox1.Items.Add(link);
                    }
                }
```

This will find links in the `<a href="...">` tags of the HTML document. If you need to find ALL links (including javascript codes, styles etc), you can use regular expression, something like this:

```
 private static readonly Regex cHttpUrlsRegex = new Regex(@"(?<url>((http|https):[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[_/.=&?%-]|[~])*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        public static IEnumerable<string> ExtractHttpUrls(string aText, string aMatch = null)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(aText)) yield break;
            var matches = cHttpUrlsRegex.Matches(aText);
            var vMatcher = aMatch == null ? null : new Regex(aMatch);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var vUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(match.Groups["url"].Value);
                if (vMatcher == null || vMatcher.IsMatch(vUrl))
                    yield return vUrl;
            }
        }

foreach (var link ExtractHttpUrls(s1))
                {
                    count++;
                       if (link.StartsWith("http") && !listBox1.Items.Contains(link))
                           listBox1.Items.Add(link);
                }
```

Comment: I'm still not getting the same results as in the source. I did in google for testing some search then went to google images then i did right click to view the page source and when i make search in the source-view and type http i see 573 as results when i type https i see 270 results. What i'm doing is marking all the source-view content paste it to a text file then open the text file and using the variabl s1 to read all the text from the file: s1 = File.ReadAllText(filename); then using the htmlagilitypack but i'm getting only 129 links.

Comment: If you do plain text search for "http" or "https" in the HTML source, you will find links that are contained in javascript codes, in image tags, in link tags, in styles and many others. With HtmlAgilityPack, you can only find links in HTML document (not in javascript, styles, etc). If you are trying to find ALL the links regardless of whether they are a part of HTML document or not, you can't use HtmlAgilityPack and you will probably need regex for that, see update to my answer